# Java - ClassCastException on downcast

Tags: java, json, gwt, casting

i would try to write an JSONparser for gwt.

For this i use the lib org.json on server side and the com.google.gwt.json.client on client side.

I build some interface's to call this two lib with the same methods.

I use:

```
public class JSONObject extends com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject implements IJSONObject
{
  ...
}
```

and

```
public class JSONObject extends org.json.JSONObject implements IJSONObject
{
  ...
}
```

So it works like a sharm, but there is one thing i wouldn't get it.

Client-side:

```
JSONParser.parseLenient( sJson ).isObject()
```

Return ans Object from Type: **"com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject"**

And i try to cast this to my custom JSONObject and get an ClassCastException.

My custom JSONObject extends from com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject and implements my IJSONobject.

So if i can't cast the object, i can't user the interface.

Thank you

Comment: Just because that method returns a reference to the parent class does mean it's of your subclass type as well.

Comment: But i know it is :P I only added methods not attributes

Comment: What part of this code: `JSONParser.parseLenient( sJson ).isObject()` uses your custom class?

Comment: Then there's your answer. Can't expect it to reference your object if it's not even using your code. Right?

Answer (score 2):

You will get ClassCastException for sure.

Reason:

You are trying to cast an object "com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject" into an object "public class JSONObject extends com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONObject", which is not possible.

Example:

```
public class TestClassCast {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    A a = new A();
    B b = new B();

    A b1 = b; // This is possible since class B extends class A

    // B a1 = a; // This is not possible, which you are trying to do in your scenario.
}


}

class A {
    A(){};
}

class B extends A {
    B(){};
}
```

Comment: But they are exactly the same, without some methods. Can i not force this?

Comment: No we cannot force this.

Comment: Have some alternate ideas how can i implement something like that?

Comment: It is not possible, since child class can be cast into parent, whereas parent class cannot be cast to child. Referring to my example code, B is child of A, so instance of B can be cast into A, whereas vice versa is not allowed. ie., A b1 = b; is allowed and B a1 = a; is not allowed.

Comment: Got it. But away form downcast have you any idea to solve my problem... it seems like the way with my interface wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

**ClassCastException on downcast**

I think you should extend from super class.
Please try this :

```
public class YourCustomJSON extends com.google.gwt.json.client.JSONValue implement IJSONobject
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: But i don't want an JSONValue?!